# Issue with BB LWUIT 1.5 TextField

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-textarea

I have problem with the LWUIT1.5 Textfield in BB . The issue is that even after I set the constraint as NUMERIC for the text field , the first character alone accepts alphabets. This happens only in BB and when Alt+key is used for entering the number, there are no issues.

If anyone has experienced such issues please help me

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text field input mode order to `new String[] {"123}}`